# I have one gravity form placing at two places on same page

Tags: wordpress, forms, form-submit, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have one gravity form placing at two places on the same page, now how can I identify the spot of submission?

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO!, while asking a questions here do share code and some of the attempts you have done to solve our issue. And also, if you have made any attempts to fix it, please edit them into your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms doesn't support multiple instances of the same form on the same page. You'll need to use a 3rd-party plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-gf-form-on-single-page/).

Once you have that setup, use the `field_values` parameter on the Gravity Forms shortcode to populate a Hidden field on your form with the placement.

```
[gravityforms id="1" field_values="placement=sidebar"]
```

```
[gravityforms id="1" field_values="placement=footer"]
```

And your Hidden field would be configured to accept this "placement" population parameter like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, let me try this.